# Push messages from PC to iPad with confirmation system

Tags: windows, ios, chat, notification

I was wondering if any of you knew of a program that would allow me to push a message from a PC (or phone) to an iPad on my local network and have it pop up full screen on the ipad (and maybe flash the screen) with a confirm button which notifies the sending device that the message has been read? I am planning to use this during a live stage performance (nothing high budget) as a way of us up in the lighting and sound box to push a message to the backstage crew (to tell them to adjust someone's mic etc) and be notified once they have seen it and confirmed it. Maybe it could even just be a 2 separate web pages, one which sends messages (and receives confirmations) and once which receives messages and is able to send confirmations to the other web page.
If no such program exists, would anybody be able to assist by possibly creating one or pushing me in the right direction to put one together? It doesn't need to be anything fancy, it only needs to work for a week.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at [Google Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/). It partially fulfills your requirement. It is basically a software which narrows down the gap between devices - (PC- Tabs - SmartPhones).Although, there is no feature available that notifies user that message has been read.